# Why is my remove event listener not functioning?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I know that similar questions were already answered on stack but for some reason their solutions don't work for me. I am trying to create a simple drag and drop game/activity. User can have only one attempt to drag an element, so if it dragged once I want to remove associated drag event listeners. Hope it makes sense. And here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="boxes">
 <div id="b1" class="box" draggable="true"><header>Vacuum Tubes</header></div>
 <div id="b2" class="box" draggable="true"><header> Eniac</header></div> 
 <div id="b3" class="box" draggable="true"><header> Transistors </header> </div> 
 <div id="b4" class="box" draggable="true"><header> Integrated Cicuits</header> </div>
 <div id="b5" class="box" draggable="true"><header> Microprocessor </header> </div>
</div>
```

In the init function I am adding the event listeners to the elements I want to drag later on.

```
function init(){
 cols = document.querySelectorAll('#boxes div.box');
 [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
 boxes.push(col);
 states.push("false");
 col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
 col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);}
}
```

**** boxes, states and cols are arrays that are defined and declared outside the `init()` function

Than in the function that handles dropping of the element I have the following code

```
dragSrcEl.removeEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
dragSrcEl.removeEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
cols[i].removeEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
cols[i].removeEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
cols[i].draggable=false;
dragSrcEl.draggable=false;
```

So as you can see I am trying prevent this element from dragging in three different ways.
And still, it doesn't work. User can still drag the element.

My question 1:
how I can remove `dragstart` and `dragend` event listener ?
My question 2:
Why my code doesn't work?

Comment: I have never used it before so I hope I did it right:
http://jsfiddle.net/3qCm6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is wide variation in behaviour among browsers. The only one I can think of that behaves the way you expect is Firefox.

The draggable attribute on its own is enough to allow drag on Internet Explorer, Edge and Chrome. Firefox on the other hand won't enter drag mode until event.dataTransfer.setData(mimetype, valuestring) is called. For selected text and images this happens automatically, which is why they are magically draggable.

So for FF to set the value you must have a dragStart handler, and once you have a handler it must return true or you still won't get drag mode.

To get uniform cross browser behaviour you must do it the FF way and set the value of draggable to indicate whether drag is to start, so as to suppress drag on IE, Edge and Chrome. Returning false might also work but you'll have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, try to check your syntax. I put your js into jsfiddle and ran the interpreter.
When you look at the console.log you can see a syntax error.

```
function init(){
cols = document.querySelectorAll('#boxes div.box');
[].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
    boxes.push(col);
    states.push("false");
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
}); /* <--- Check this here. */
}
init();
console.log($('#boxes > div.box'));
```

Then when i run it after jslint (which says it's ok), there is only a TypeError with your push function.

Cheers
Laidback

Comment: Without JSHint, you can also see that `boxes` and `states` are not defined. Since the events are attached, that's not the problem. The OP is experiencing the opposite: the events can't be removed.

Comment: Boxes and states are arrays defined outside the init function. 
var cols;
var dragSrcEl = null;
var boxes = new Array();
var states = new Array();

Comment: Also I was running the website with safari's error console and firefox  's web console. thanks for the tip though.